# What equations, precisely, are meant here by "product identities," and what is the combinatorics that describes this "very rapid" increase?

Tags: independence, combinatorics

The following is said:

> Events $A$ and $B$ are independent, written $A \perp B$, if $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$, or, equivalently, if $P(B \mid A) = P(B)$, and each of these is equivalent to the more symmetric looking multiplication rule, $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$.
> We need a concept of the independence of 3, 4, ... events, and this seems to be feasible only by extending the multiplication rule. For example, events $A$, $B$, and $C$ are (mutually) independent if
> $$P(AB) = P(A) P(B), \ \ \ \ P(AC) = P(A)P(C), \ \ \ P(BC) = P(B)P(C), \tag{1}$$
> and
> $$P(ABC) = P(A)P(B)P(C). \tag{2}$$
> The condition (1) is called pairwise independence, and it is possible for this condition to hold but not (2). The definition for 4, 5, ... events is similar, with the number of product identities increasing very rapidly with the number of events.

I'm curious about this part:

> ... with the number of product identities increasing very rapidly with the number of events.

What equations, precisely, are meant here by "product identities," and what is the combinatorics that describes this "very rapid" increase? With regards to the latter question, is there, for instance, some kind of factorial increase in "product identities," dependent on the number of events?

Comment: How many different subsets of a collection of $n$ events would you need to consider in generalizing the concept of independence?

Comment: @whuber since we’re dealing with subsets, is it $2^n$? Although, if that’s correct, I’m not completely sure what the reasoning is.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236659/number-of-subsets-of-a-set-having-r-elements.